# Warning: Unable to write "dest/full/" file (Error code: EISDIR)

Tags: gruntjs

I've got one warning: "Unable to write "dest/full/" file (Error code: EISDIR)" while **htmlrefs** tried to complete its task.

```
htmlrefs: {
        dist: {
            /** @required  - string including grunt glob variables */
            src: 'src/*.html',
            /** @optional  - string directory name*/
            dest: 'dest/full/',
            options: {
            /** @optional  - references external files to be included */
            /*
                includes: {
                    analytics: './ga.inc' // in this case it's google analytics (see sample below)
                },
                */
            /** any other parameter included on the options will be passed for template evaluation */
                buildNumber: 1
            }
        }
    },
```

Of course I have no new files.
Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

I don't know if you figured it out, but I'm pretty sure you need to add "expand: true" in the "dist" object.  I don't know why it was left out of the documentation.  Try that.

```
htmlrefs: {
    dist: {
        expand: true,
        src: 'src/*.html',
        dest: 'dest/full/',
        options: {
            includes: {
                analytics: './ga.inc'
            },
            buildNumber: 1
        }
    }
},
```